# Logging the SOAP message through ValidationEventHandler

Tags: cxf

Here's the thing: 
I am trying to set up a schema validation through cxf with a custom validation event handler. 
My configuration looks something like this:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="personEndpoint" address="/person"
    serviceClass="org.apache.servicemix.samples.wsdl_first.Person"
    wsdlURL="wsdl/person.wsdl">
    <cxf:properties>
        <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
        <entry key="jaxb-validation-event-handler">
            <bean class="org.dpytel.servicemix.camel.MyCustomHandler" />
        </entry>
    </cxf:properties>
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

This is working fine - the schema validation is checked and when errors are encountered, "MyCustomHandler" gets executed.
My problem is that I want to save the whole message that caused the validation error to a file, but inside "MyCustomHandler" I don't have this information available (only some error message and the location)

Is there some other way to validate schema with cxf and log the message if something goes wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CXF Fault Interceptor to access the message content while validation exception will cause a fault:

http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.4.1/cxf_interceptors/CXFInterceptorImplMessage.html